# Tower: What is causing "[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details"

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-tower

I am just starting to work with Ansible Tower and made a project and then a job template under that project that uses a small initial test playbook (Test.yml):

```
---
- hosts: east01.xxxxx.com
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  - name: test
    shell: echo 'line one line two line three' >> /tmp/abcdef.txt
```

and, when I try to run that playbook by clicking the "rocketship" in Tower, it looks like it is working:

```
Identity added: /tmp/awx_35003_yehjodc1/artifacts/35003/ssh_key_data (/tmp/awx_35003_yehjodc1    /artifacts/35003/ssh_key_data)
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use
-vvvv to see details
PLAY [east01.xxxxx.com] **********************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [east01.xxxxx.com]
TASK [test] ********************************************************************
changed: [east01.xxxxx.com]
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
east01.xxxxx.com : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

and it looks like that is actually working (I can see the file on the target machine being modified when I run the playbook), but can someone tell me what is causing that WARNING:

```
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use
-vvvv to see details
```

??

Also the warning says to "use -vvvv" and I was wondering where/how do I do that (since I am running this playbook under Tower)?

Thanks!  Jim

EDIT: I just did a test, where I ran the same yaml file using ansible-playbook (command line) and it ran without that warning, so I guess that the warning is something to do with some difference between ansible-playbook and Tower?

Comment: (a) did you try `- debug: var=groups` to see what groups are being used in Tower? (b) [of course Tower has verbosity control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.8.1/html/userguide/job_templates.html#create-a-job-template)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your version of `ansible-playbook` is probably older than the version of Ansible being used in Tower.

In recent versions of Ansible, group names must be valid variable names. See [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) for details on what constitutes a valid variable name.

If `east01.xxxxx.com` is a group name, the periods are the problem. Otherwise, check you group names for anything not a letter, digit, or `_`.

Comment: larsks - I found the reason - in the inventory I had selected in Tower, there was one group whose group name has a dash ("-") in it and there was a red question mark next to its name.  Actually, also, when I look at the list of inventories that particular inventory name ("Sandbox") has a red question mark next to it, probably because that group had that base group name?  Thanks,

Answer (score 20):

This warning appears when you are using dashes in your inventory file when you declaring your group names.
For instance if your inventory file looks like this:

```
[web-servers]
ubuntu ansible_ssh_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Ansible will throw that warning.
**Instead, if you will be using underscores**, the warning is gone.

```
[web_servers]
ubuntu ansible_ssh_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: NB: when doing this change in AWX/Ansible Tower, the old group is kept and must be manually deleted. A simple replacement in the inventory which is synced from a git repo is not enough.